# googlemapのtspsolver の入手と使いかた

Tags: google-maps

複数の拠点を経由(１０拠点以上)する配送の最適な巡回ルートを計算する仕組みを作ろうとしています。
そこでgooglemapのtspsolver の入手と使いかたを教えてください。なかなか探すことができませんでした。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

質問の意図は、TSP Solverの機能を提供するGoogleのAPIの所在でしょうか。

Google Maps Directions API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=ja

ウェイポイントに複数の拠点を指定します。
最大23 か所の地点を通過するルートを計画できます。
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=ja#Waypoints